# Vba dont change variable value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question about VBA. My script should go through the table an Stop if it finds and empty value. So I have 2 Problems with my code:

```
Sub BudgetKontoRechnen()
Dim row As Long, column As String, locSum As Double, sumRow As Integer

row = 4
column = "A"

Do
    ' Point 1
    If Len(Range(column & row).Value) = 0 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    Set sumCell = Range(column & row).Offset(0, 1)
    sumRow = 0
    locSum = 0

    Do
        sumRow = sumRow + 1
        If Len(sumCell.Offset(sumRow, 0).Value) = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        locSum = locSum + CDbl(sumCell.Offset(sumRow, 0).Value)
    Loop

    nextCol = Split(Range(column & row).Offset(0, 2).Address, "$")
    column = nextCol(1)
    ' Point 2
    sumCell.Value = locSum
Loop

End Sub
```

I added some points for orientation:

At point 1 column is always "A".
At point 2 it should change the column to the second-next column, so when check column at this point, is says C. But in the next loop its again A. I don't know why...

And second: every code I add After the last line (sumCell.Value = locSum) is not executed. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I suggest you to use `Cells(row, column)` with row and column integers  instead of `Range()`, it should be easier to iterate in a `Do ... Loop`.

Comment: Weird, but the code works for me, sorry for wrong answer, already deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

You way to organize your code is odd. I suggest you to use `Cells()` instead of `Range()` to access your data, and to move the continuation test in the `Do` line, where it belongs, instead of putting it later with an `Exit Do`.

```
Sub BudgetKontoRechnen()
    Dim row As Long, column As Long
    Dim sumCell As Range
    Dim locSum As Double, sumRow As Long

    row = 4
    column = 1

    Do While Cells(row, column).Text <> ""
        ' Point 1
        Set sumCell = Cells(row, column + 1)

        sumRow = 1
        locSum = 0

        Do While sumCell.Offset(sumRow, 0).Text <> ""
            locSum = locSum + CDbl(sumCell.Offset(sumRow, 0).value)
            sumRow = sumRow + 1
        Loop

        ' Point 2
        sumCell.value = locSum

        column = column + 2
    Loop

End Sub
```

I've also changed the test from `.Value` to `.Text` checks, not sure if it is better.

Note that the code interact with the ActiveSheet, you might want to explicit which sheet you work on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified to what follows:

```
Sub BudgetKontoRechnen()
    Dim iCol As Long

    With Range("A4", Cells(4, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft))
        For iCol = 1 To .Columns.count Step 2
            If WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Cells(1, iCol).Text) <> vbNullString Then
                With .Cells(1, iCol + 1)
                    .Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.Transpose(.Parent.Range(.Offset(1), .Offset(1).End(xlDown)).Value))
                End With
            End If
        Next iCol
    End With
End Sub
```